# Jquery plugin not working for elements loaded via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Description: I'm working on a project that loads elements with an expiration date derived from my database.  I'm using a Jquery plugin that uses the HTML5 Data Type Attribute as the "end date".  All works well when the elements are loaded into the DOM but I can't figure out how to make this plugin run on the elements loaded via ajax that triggers from a scroll function.  Admittedly Javascript isn't my strong suit, and I'm not looking for a coded answer ... I'm just looking for direction.  There is clearly something that I simply don't know or the way I'm understanding my problem is off because 4 days of Googling and trial and error hasn't produced any results.  Thanks everyone!

EDIT: This is what I've tried -

1) an ajax complete function -

```
$(document).ajaxComplete( function(){ $('.countdown').countdown(); });
```

2)adding a script tag echoed in my php results -

```
<script>$('.countdown').countdown();</script>
```

3)adding it into my .scroll function  -

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            if (is_loading == false) { // stop loading many times for the same page
                // set is_loading to true to refuse new loading
                is_loading = true;

                // display the waiting loader
                $('#loader').show(500);

                // execute an ajax query to load more statments
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'JSON-TEST/load_more.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {last_id:last_id},
                    success:function(data){
                        // now we have the response, so hide the loader
                        $('#loader').hide(500);
                        // append: add the new statments to the existing data
                        $('#content').append(data);
                        // set is_loading to false to accept new loading
                        is_loading = false;
                        $('.countdown').countdown();

                    }
                });

            }
       }
    });
});
```

All three successfully call the script. I can tell because that div actually gets populated with content however , I get all zeros in the timer.

Comment: Re-initialise the plugin in ajax success.

Comment: What plugin are you using? Maybe you should use event delegation?

Comment: @ShaunakD, I attempted to re-initialise the plugin but without success.  Can you describe how to do so?  I've tried recalling it with getScript, and I've tried to name the main function in the plugin and use that as a callback.

Comment: You should add the code you ve tried in the question. So we can debug or help on it.

Comment: @putvande, here is the link to the script on GitHub - https://github.com/kalebheitzman/jquery-countdown

Comment: Please see my edits above, also, this is my first time posting a question so please bear with me.  Again, any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use .on method with the event delegation form. This basically consists on delegating the listening of the event to the closest parent node of the element that you're trying to listen.
As a rule of thumb always delegate the event to the closest parent that already exists into the dom. DONT go all the way up to document because of perf reasons.

Something like:

$("closest-parent-of-the-element").on ("event-that-you-want", "element-loaded-through-ajax", function (e) { 
// listener code here
})

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Guillermo, but I'm not sure that addresses my problem.  I understand this method will add the event listener to current and future elements but, my problem is that the jquery countdown plugin runs on all elements with the class of .countdown and have a datatype attribute but there is no specific trigger like a click event.  The plugin runs on the dynamically loaded elements but it does not recognize the info in the datatype attribute.  I hope I'm explaining that right?  Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: As it turns out I was completely wrong in the way I was looking at the problem ... The plugin was running on the dynamically added elements but the plugin was not able to use to the data-type attribute.  I changed the plugin for a different countdown and ran the script on each element by id and it's working like a champ!  Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use use live : http://api.jquery.com/live/

it works for elements loaded after the initial document.ready

Comment: That has been long deprecated and removed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and sorry for the bad advice.